# Client server best practice java

Tags: java, sockets, server, client

In a simple game development is it better to have the server handle most of it or to have the client handle do it?. For instance a simple hangman game. Have the client sent over the letter and the server handle the calculations and send back the hit or miss + 'blanked out string'. or to have the server send blank string and do the comparison on the client side. What are the best practice in terms of socket programming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See there are two kinds of network-based programs:

1. Pure network-based: Display on client-side and everything else on the server.
2. Standalone: Database and Model on server and controller and display on client-side. Resources are also present on the client-side.

In terms of socket programming, I would prefer Pure network-based apps. You should consider the memory and time complexity in both the ways and then choose the best one.